# MacOSX Server vpnd "CANNOT_LOAD_BUNDLE_ERR"

Tags: vpn, mac-osx

My office vpn server (a mac osx server) doesn't seem reliable. Clients loose connectivity to the server after 15-20 minutes or more of activity. Often the the first time authentication is re-tried the server will not respond - and no contact is shown on the server side.

When I tried "sudo serveradmin status vpnd" to look into the issue - I got

> vpnd:error = "CANNOT_LOAD_BUNDLE_ERR"

Google searches have turned up no explanation
EDIT: New wrinkle, it status began behaving normally for a brief period of hours, and then went back to doing this.